# Real Time File Sync - Mirroring Locally

Tags: sync

I need to sync a number of files in one folder to other folder on the same machine (no sub folders involved).  I have tried hard linking i.e. ln dir1 dir2 but it is not sync'ing/replicating.  Everything I have read so far is about real time syncing between servers - I do not want that.  I simply(?) want the files (4 of them) in dir1 to be duplicated in dir2 whenever one of them in dir1 changes.

Comment: Dependant upon the size of the files (free or paid for service), have you considered [Dropbox](https://linoxide.com/tools/install-dropbox-ubuntu/)? It creates a folder in your home directory and any files you access from either place (Dbox or your local drive) automatically sync immediately without further user intervention. Dropbox is available from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Hard linking works on the same disk, but does not actually copy any data. Only the *same* file is reflected in another directory (possibly) with another name. What do you want to accomplish? Create a second copy of your files in the same machine, but on different disks or on the *same* disk? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Please, [edit] your question and give more information.

Comment: Check https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=realtimesync .

Comment: Specifically I want to have a real time sync of the files logins.json, favicons,sqlite, places.sqlite and key4.db that are in the .mozilla profile folder to another folder on my hard drive that I can save to the cloud (e.g. Dropbox).  I have tried putting the whole .mozilla folder in the Dropbox folder but at times Dropbox doesn't like it because, when surfing, files are being changed continuously.  Backing up these specific files will allow me restore the key components of firefox (bookmarks, logons etc)

Comment: "Backing up these specific files will allow me restore the key components of firefox (bookmarks, logons etc)" the same effect is achieved by creating a [Firefox account](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer)

Comment: I am really confused: The OP wants real time backing up of some files to the Dropbox account. But, at the same time, says that "Dropbox doesn't like it because this directory (and also the files mentioned) are changed continously". So, I want to clear out: Is a real time backup needed (which does not seem a good backup strategy to me)? Or a periodic (say, once a day when Firefox is off) is wanted? BTW, by hardlinking my file(s) to file(s) under the Dropbox directory DOES work, and files are uploaded regularly by Dropbox. However, it seems that the OP now wants another solution.

Comment: I solved this by hard linking the files I need to another folder on my hard disk.  I find it is easier to get cloud services to 'see' and work consistently with these files when they are in a 'normal' folder rather than a hidden folder.  I used the terminal command ln '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/profilenumber.default-release/places.sqlite'  '/home/usernameDropbox/mozilla/firefox/profilenumber.default-release/places.sqlite'